# check an element in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

So I want to use an XSL to format a date before its sent through a Web Service but I also want to run a check that if the DOB field is blank it remains blank and if it has a date in it, it will go ahead an format the date.

Now I have got the XSL to format the date - however I can't seem to get the condition working that if its empty leave it empty

XML before going through XSL:

```
<BriefDetails>
    <ObjectID>
        <flt:ObjectType>C1</flt:ObjectType>
    </ObjectID>
</BriefDetails>
<Name>
    <Title>Dr</Title>
    <Forename>Paul</Forename>
    <Surname>Smith</Surname>
    <flt:Preferred>true</flt:Preferred>
</Name>
<ContactEmails>
    <EmailAddress>mail@mail.com</EmailAddress>
    <flt:Preferred>true</flt:Preferred>
</ContactEmails>
<DateOfBirth />
<ContactPostals>
    <AddressNumber>34</AddressNumber>
    <AddressLine>Hopeless Road</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Maghera</AddressLine>
    <Postcode>BT74 2TY</Postcode>
    <flt:Preferred>true</flt:Preferred>
</ContactPostals>
<ContactPhones>
    <Number>5545454</Number>
    <flt:Preferred>false</flt:Preferred>
</ContactPhones>
<ContactPhones>
    <Number>5454545</Number>
    <flt:Preferred>false</flt:Preferred>
</ContactPhones>
```

XML after XSL:

```
<BriefDetails>
    <ObjectID>
        <flt:ObjectType>C1</flt:ObjectType>
    </ObjectID>
</BriefDetails>
<Name>
    <Title>Dr</Title>
    <Forename>Paul</Forename>
    <Surname>Smith</Surname>
    <flt:Preferred>true</flt:Preferred>
</Name>
<ContactEmails>
    <EmailAddress>mail@mail.com</EmailAddress>
    <flt:Preferred>true</flt:Preferred>
</ContactEmails>
***<DateOfBirth>--</DateOfBirth>***
<ContactPostals>
    <AddressNumber>34</AddressNumber>
    <AddressLine>Hopeless Road</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Maghera</AddressLine>
    <Postcode>BT74 2TY</Postcode>
    <flt:Preferred>true</flt:Preferred>
</ContactPostals>
<ContactPhones>
    <Number>5545454</Number>
    <flt:Preferred>false</flt:Preferred>
</ContactPhones>
<ContactPhones>
    <Number>5454545</Number>
    <flt:Preferred>false</flt:Preferred>
</ContactPhones>
```

Above you will see the DOB as --

XSL being used:

```
<xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
    <xsl:element name="DateOfBirth">
        <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="dateParam" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="dateParam" />
    <!-- input format mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy -->
    <!-- output format yyyy-mm-dd -->

    <!-- parse out the day, month and year -->
    <xsl:variable name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($dateParam,'/')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="month">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($dateParam,'/'),'/')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="year">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($dateParam,'/'),'/')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- now print them out. Pad with 0 where necessary. -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
    <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
    <xsl:if test="string-length($month) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$month" />
    <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
    <xsl:if test="string-length($day) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day" />
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried adding in a condition:

```
<xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
    <xsl:for-each select="DateOfBirth">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(DateOfBirth) != 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateParam" select="DateOfBirth" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="dateParam" />
    <!-- input format mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy -->
    <!-- output format yyyy-mm-dd -->

    <!-- parse out the day, month and year -->
    <xsl:variable name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($dateParam,'/')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="month">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($dateParam,'/'),'/')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="year">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($dateParam,'/'),'/')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- now print them out. Pad with 0 where necessary. -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
    <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
    <xsl:if test="string-length($month) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$month" />
    <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
    <xsl:if test="string-length($day) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'0'" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day" />
</xsl:template>
```

but this now strips out the DOB in the XML

Any advice on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your IF condition

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(DateOfBirth) != 0">
```

You are already positioned on the **DateOfBirth** element at this point, so this is actually looking for a child element called **DateOfBirth** in the current element, rather than the value of the current element itself.

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(.) != 0">
```

Actually, you also seem to have added an unnecessary **xsl:for-each** too. Your template should really look like this

```
<xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
    <DateOfBirth>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(.) != 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateParam" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </DateOfBirth>
</xsl:template>
```

As a side note, there is no need for using **xsl:element** for a static element name, just write out the element directly.

In fact, there is another way to do this without the need for the **xsl:if**. You can have the condition within the template match

```
<xsl:template match="DateOfBirth[string-length(.) != 0]">
    <DateOfBirth>
        <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
             <xsl:with-param name="dateParam" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </DateOfBirth>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
    <DateOfBirth />
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT will also match the more specific template first, so the second template will only be matched when **DateOfBirth** is empty. Further more, if you were using the identity transform in your XSLT, you wouldn't actually need the second template at all.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply!

this pretty much covers what I need - though am still having an issue if the date is blank an error will be flagged - but from the XML I can see DOB is not being stripped out. Think I need to apply some logic into the WS as the DOB is expected. Apply logic that if DOB is blank its not included in WS.